# 4D Geometry Book

Tags: geometry, soft-question, book-recommendation

A friend of mine is writing a book on female scientists and mathematicians, and one of the subjects will be Alicia Boole Stott, a British mathematician who studied 4D geometry and polytopes. Are there any books people could recommend for someone who is new to the topic that explain 4D well or help with the visual understanding?

Comment: You might enjoy looking at the March 17th post on this blog by John Baez https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/

Comment: How much higher-level mathematics do you know? The classic reference is probably Coxeter's [Regular Polytopes](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Polytopes-H-S-Coxeter/dp/0486614808#productDescription_secondary_view_div_1467928272629), but from what I've heard it requires quite some prior knowledge of mathematics, e.g., group theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:
D. M. Y. Sommerville, [*An Introduction to the Geometry of N Dimensions*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486604942) (1958)
... written more in the style that A. B. Stott would have been familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Rudy Rucker's book, "The Fourth Dimension: A Guided Tour of the Higher Universes", is aimed at those new to the topic.